# C++ endless cin console prompt

Tags: c++

I've made a simple program which is supposed to ask the user for the length of a set, fill it with numbers and find the minimal value of that set. When I run the code, program works fine until the last number of the set is entered. Console prompt keeps blinking but it doesn't react to the keyboard. The program stops at this point. I don't understand why it doesn't just stop asking for input. I'm using CodeBlocks 16.01 if that matters. Here is is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int len;
    cout << "How many elements?" << endl;
    cin >> len;
    int myset[len];
    int temp;
    cout << "Enter " << len <<" numbers: " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        myset[x] = temp;
        cout << endl;
    }
    int mini;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i = 0)
        {
            mini = myset[i];
        }
        else if(myset[i] < mini)
        {
            mini = myset[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Minimal value of this set: " << mini << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have to call `cin.clear()` and consume the erroneous input after such occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set i to 0 in the if(i = 0) line... I suppose you want to write "if (i==0)"

Comment: Jeez, such a typical mistake. The previous IDE I used would remind me of such bugs. Thanks!